# Call Overriden Method from Base Class in JS

Tags: javascript

I have something along these lines

```
class Example {

    abstractMethod() {
      // do things in derived class
    }

    concreteMethod() {
        abstractMethod();
    }
}

class DerivedExample extends Example {

    abstractMethod() {
      // do custom things
    }
}

DerivedExample de = new DerivedExample();
de.concreteMethod(); // This is calling Example.abstractMethod();
```

How do I get it to call DerivedExample.abstractMethod()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave `abstractMethod` undefined and then set it in the subclass.

```js
class Example {
    abstractMethod;
    concreteMethod() {
        this.abstractMethod();
    }
}

class DerivedExample extends Example {
    abstractMethod = function() {
        console.log('works');
    }
}

let de = new DerivedExample;
de.concreteMethod();
```

Comment: I just pasted into the console of my browser and it worked. If what you are doing doesn't work, you need to provide more information.

Comment: I get an error TypeError: abstractMethod is not a function

Comment: Did you copy and paste? What browser are you using?